# phpmyadmin What is wrong with my Event?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have created an event for my phpmyadmin and it does not work. I want to reset all of the rows with my credits column. Here is the image

[image]

```
 update CUSTOMERS 
    set NETFLIX=5
```

Comment: be clear with your codes.

Comment: at lease tell what you expect and what you need do do

Comment: @b0sss hello did you success about this, i have same issue but nothing clear in stackoverflow and google thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your event scheduler active?

On the phpMyAdmin Events page, look in the bottom right area for "Event scheduler status" -- make sure the toggle is green and showing "On" like this:

[image: Showing the Event scheduler status]

Also check the server time, you can do so by going to the SQL tab and running the query `SELECT NOW();` -- there's an off chance your server thinks it's February or 2016 or something.

Are your column names really all caps? It might fail if you're not matching the case. You can check this by copying and pasting the query in to the SQL tab.

Comment: please goes to here https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11974#issuecomment-185170574 i have another issue, i have been make enabled status event but it's not working, thanks for reading this